# Excess water streaming through LG washer/dryer combo

Tags: water, appliances, washing-machine, laundry

I have a front-loading washer/dryer from LG. The "wash" cycle appears to run normally with the water being turned on and off multiple times. However, the wash cycle concludes with streaming water which does not stop even when the machine is turned off. It only stops when I turn off the cold water intake supply line. I can turn the water on again and run a "spin" cycle with no difficulties (water is never turned on for "Spin & Drain"), but the flood of water returns near the beginning of the "dry" cycle and, again, doesn't turn off when the cycle is stopped or paused.

We've tried typical troubleshooting steps including making sure all drains and clear of clogs, powering the device off, and clearing the drain catch which did not resolve the problem. The unit still heats up during the "dry" cycle, it's not not effective when being flooded by extra water. Water is internal and doesn't spread outside of the unit.

Any ideas of what's happening and how we can fix it, or is the only option to go to a professional? Thanks in advance for your help!

TLDR:

- Wash: everything seems to run fine but water continues to stream at the end of wash.
- Spin & drain: completes successfully and clothes are left slightly damp.
- Dry: What is supposed to be a slight stream of water is instead a flood. Clothes are left drenched.
- Water flow does not stop when machine is turned off, needs to be turned off from the water supply line.
- Problem appears limited to cold water at end of wash phase & in the dry phase.

Comment: what is your water pressure

Comment: Usually pretty strong, but this is a new issue I've never encountered before and water pressure for the rest of the condo hasn't changed

Comment: Ok, so if that's the case I probably replace the water intake valve? Or is there something else I should check first?

Comment: Have you done a search on your model of washer to find and execute the manufacturer's trouble shooting steps?

Comment: @FreeMan : Yes I have. Nothing in their troubleshooting steps helped, but it was the typical bland advice like "turn off and turn on again", "clear all drains", etc and nothing that was problem specific.

Comment: Glad to hear that you at least tried that. Letting us know is helpful, avoids wasting time asking...

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the module I will take a SWAG: I would say it is the control board, best get a pro to replace it but check the cost a new washer it may be more cost effective to replace the washer.  Initially it sounded like the solenoid valve but if you place a meter on it I believe you will find it has been energized at the wrong time and at other times turns off. I believe the only thing that normally controls it is the main control board.

Comment: Thanks! What makes you think control board rather than a problem with the water intake valve?

If I turn the water off, the water stream doesn't continue when I turn it on again even when running the same cycle. The water stream also doesn't respond to unplugging the machine. To me, this makes it sound like the input valve is opening too much and can't close, but I don't have any real technical knowledge.

Comment: In parts of the cycle it turns off.j Also I mentioned to measure the solenoid voltage to validate that assumption.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up replacing the water inlet valve which solved the main problem. There's no longer a rush of water at the beginning of dry/end of wash that threatens to flood the machine. I'm still having some issues where later in the dry cycle excess water is being added, which I'm back to square one with -- it seems like I can run a wash cycle with normal water pressure just fine, then turn the water pressure down to run the dry cycle.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, if you close the water supply valve it stops, and it does not start when you open the valve.

That is a NC (normal closed valve) solenoid valve.

When it gets power it opens.

Power to the Solenoid valve magnetizes the shaft and valve opens.

When power is shut off the spring inside pushes the valve in closed position.

If you have weak spring and high water pressure the valve stays open.

Comment: Great, thank you for the insight. So if the spring is weak, it may be only trying to open up a trickle but forced to open much more?